# CodeRush not working with c++ visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, coderush

I installed the newest version.
The GUI (CodeRush buttons) is there but none of them work.
Also other features does not work (tips when placing caret over code or debugging - none of them work).

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly support for C++ has been deprecated within CodeRush.

See [this post](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/CodeRush/cpp11.xml) from mid 2013

Comment: then what's the newest version I can use with c++?

Comment: I'm not sure of the specifics of this. I suggest asking via http://devexpress.com/sc/ They will have more up to date information. however since VS2013 was released ~5 months after the date of the post, I don't think you'll have much joy there.